# Rails mechanize can't access page that requires logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am trying click a link that appears after I've logged in with Rails + Mechanize, but it returns "Cookie should be enabled". I've checked the cookie in the my Mechanize object (`mechanize.cookie_jar.save_as('cookies.yml')`) and it exists and is the same cookie my browser sent when I accessed the site (I checked with FireBug). But I can't login.

Why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: Login is tricky. Often you will have to look at the network traffic and do a post from mechanize. Odds are good it is not a cookie problem.